# Select from database only values not seen before

Tags: php, pdo

Let's say that I have a database with this data stored:

```
Email-Link-Link2
1E@231-Example1-Example2
1E@231-Example3-Example4
```

How can I select all of this value with a PDO query excluding those seen before, so in this case 1E@231,will select only one time.

Comment: update what you have tried in ques

Comment: please add more details, code examples

Comment: In database table you can have a  flag. This flag is set to '1' when dipslayed. From beginning it is '0''

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) While wording and formatting of this question [seem substandard](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it looks *almost* answerable: please edit into your question whether you want *one (the first?) attribute tuple per email address per select*, or *one attribute tuple per email address **exactly once** over a sequence of "unrelated" selects*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand what you said, this is your answer:
**Connexion to data base with PDO**

```
<?php 
//CONNEXION TO DATA BASE WITH PDO...
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_data_base', 'the_user', 'Your_password', $pdo_options);
//end of connexion to data_base
;?>
```

**NOW getting data from data base with not duplication(you can use sql function DISTINCT**

```
<?php
$sc=$base->query("SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM table_where_data_stored");
while($data_distinct =$sc->fetch()){
//your data will be displayed here

;}
;?>
```

May this help you!!

Answer (score 0):

To evade double selection commonly one use the DISTINCT statement, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM myTable
```

But the best way to evade double-selection is to evade redundant entries to the database. As far as I understand the two entries in your database the second one is an update, and you don't want to overwrite the previous entry. This is a well known problem, and commonly solved like this:

There is a certain date from when on the new eMail should be used, so add a field "valid_from" and add this WHERE statement to your query:

```
WHERE valid_from > GETDATE()
```

`GETDATE()` returns a datetime, therefore it's enough to select "greater than".